# How to manipulate objects created/edited/deleted by a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have 3 classes :

```
public class Category  
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Category Parent {get;set;}
    public List<Category> Children {get;set;}
    public bool IsMainCategory {get;set;}
}

public class Item
{
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public Category MainCategory {get;set;}
    public List<CategoryValue> Values {get;set;}
}

public class CategoryValue
{
    public Category Category {get;set;}
    public Item Item {get;set;}
    public double Value {get;set;}
}
```

I want to create a `DataGrid` in such a way that,

1. Its column headers will be the names of all the child categories of a main category which has a true value for `IsMainCategory` except for the first column which will have "Item Description" as the header.
2. Its rows will correspond to `Item` objects and each of these `Item`s should have their `MainCategory` set to the above mentioned main category.
3. Every cell of a row (Except the first cell) should bind with the `Value` property of a corresponding `CategoryValue` object.

I wrote the code to do 1, but I can't figure out how to implement the other two requirements. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple technique is to transform the data in your POCOs into a datatable that you then bind to the DataGrid.

The DataTable is only used for display purposes. All your logic works against the POCOs